# Mongo Replica Set behind Firewall

Tags: java, mongodb

Given you run a current version (3.2) of MongoDB as a replica set in your network consisting of 3 nodes:

```
mongo1.local
mongo2.local
mongoarbiter.local
```

Now those nodes should be available via public internet (restricted via FW). mongo1 and mongo2 will get a VIP on the firewall and some valid A-Records:

```
mongo1.example.com
mongo2.example.com
```

The arbiter is not exposed.

Now some client implementations just work fine (python) if you pass the external DNS names in via connection string. But others (Java) will fail to connect since the replica set only knows its internal names. The clients will parse the list of nodes provided by the rs, notice that the externel name it has connected to is not in the list and fail:

```
Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo1.example.com:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 0, 14]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=3, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=5305689, setName='mongo-rs', canonicalAddress=mongo1.local:27017, hosts=[mongo2.local:27017, mongo1.local:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[mongo3.local:27017], primary='mongo1.local:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=5821da77ccc118202cd2b75d, setVersion=3}
```

Is there any solution to this other than messing with /etc/hosts on the clients system?

BTW: this does the trick with the js client lib but looks a bit dirty as well:

```
replSet.connectWithNoPrimary
```

Answer (score 3):

Official MongoDB drivers implement a [Server Discovery and Monitoring (SDAM)](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst) specification, which is available on GitHub in the [`mongodb/specifications` repository](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications). The SDAM spec goes into more detail on expected behaviour and rationale for drivers.

The current expectation is that [clients will always use the hostnames listed in the replica set config](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#user-content-clients-use-the-hostnames-listed-in-the-replica-set-config-not-the-seed-list), not the seed list provided in a connection string. The primary motivation for doing so is to enable automatic failover and reconfiguration based on an agreed replica set configuration (which includes hostnames and ports).

> Is there any solution to this other than messing with /etc/hosts on the clients system?

If you do not require failover you could connect to a single server rather than using a replica set connection. A standalone/direct connection should not implement any server discovery.

However, if you are connecting to anything other than a standalone server there aren't any workarounds at the moment outside of fiddling your hostname resolution to match the replica set config or extending your networking perimeter (eg. using a VPN).

A relevant feature suggestion to upvote/watch is: [SERVER-1889: Support different networks / nics for client & replication traffic](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1889). This could allow separation of the internal network communication for the replica set from the client connections.

Answer (score 2):

If you set up a sharded cluster then you can just connect directly to the *mongos* process, and let that worry about the internal/external host names of the nodes in the replica set.

If you make your replicaset part of a [sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/), then all the client connections should go through a [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/) server. The mongos maintains its own connections to the nodes in the replica set (and can do so using the internal names mongo1.local etc.); the client only connects to the mongos, and is allowed to do so using any name it likes - it does not have to match the hostnames used internally.

So, even if you won't want to use sharding for data scaling, it might be useful to you for avoiding the problem of addressing a replica set by external host names?